# My facebook login apps cannot access. (keep loading page every second)

Tags: codeigniter, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-login

I cannot use my facebook login app.
It just happened today. It's work on yesterday.
URL keep changing and reload every second.

Example:
from
[http://www.myurl.com/welcome/signInWithFB?code=123123213&state=454545454545454#*=*](http://www.myurl.com/welcome/signInWithFB?code=123123213&state=454545454545454#_=_)
to
[http://www.myurl.com/welcome/signInWithFB?code=56565656&state=787878787878#*=*](http://www.myurl.com/welcome/signInWithFB?code=56565656&state=787878787878#_=_)

and keep changing forever.

I'm use codigniter

My controler:

```
public function signInWithFB(){
        session_start();
        $fb_config = array(
            'appId'  => 'my id',
            'secret' => 'my secret'
        );

        $this->load->library('facebook', $fb_config);

        $user = $this->facebook->getUser();

        if ($user) {
            try {
                $data['user_profile'] = $this->facebook
                    ->api('/me');
                $data['friends'] = $this->facebook->api('/me/friends');
                $_SESSION['friends']= $data['friends'];

            } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
                $user = null;
            }
        }

        if ($user) {
            $data['logout_url'] = $this->facebook
                ->getLogoutUrl();
        } else {
            $data['login_url'] = $this->facebook
                ->getLoginUrl(
                    array(
                        'scope' => 'email, user_friends'
                    )
                );
        }
        if(isset($data['user_profile'])){
            $_SESSION['id']= $data['user_profile']['id'];
            $_SESSION['username']= $data['user_profile']['name'];
            $_SESSION['email']= $data['user_profile']['email'];
            $_SESSION['avatar'] = $this->dbs->getAvatar($_SESSION['username']);


        }


        $this->dbs->insertUserFromFB();

        $this->load->view('signInWithFB',$data);

    }
```

My View:

```
<?php
if (@$user_profile): ?>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=<?=base_url('welcome/profile');?>" />
<?php else: ?>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=<?=$login_url;?>" />
<?php endif; ?>
Please Wait...
```

PS. I tried to find solution but It happened for every web browsers for me.(not only IE as I found)

Thank you for advance.

Comment: Why are you doing `if (@$user_profile)`? Is it sending notices if you remove the `@`?  If so, post them here, it might be useful information.  Probably unrelated, but instead of the meta refresh, you can use `redirect ('welcome/profile')` right in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Right after the FB getUser call, add `print_r($user)` and see what is there. You might have a FB config issue. It looks like your code is probably catching that exception and making `$user=null` and your problem cascades.  In that catch, do an `echo $e->getMessage ()` and FB will probably tell you what the problem is.

Oh, and you'll probably have to `die()` right after the print_r/echo lines so that it won't just reload over and over on you.